# Subsetting Lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, google-api

From a Google API query I receive the following output in Python 3.0:

```
{'address_components': [{'long_name': '128',
    'short_name': '128',
    'types': ['street_number']},
    {'long_name': 'Mercedesstraße',
    'short_name': 'Mercedesstraße',
    'types': ['route']},
    {'long_name': 'Untertürkheim',
   'short_name': 'Untertürkheim',
   'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']},
   {'long_name': 'Stuttgart',
   'short_name': 'Stuttgart',
   'types': ['locality', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'Stuttgart',
   'short_name': 'Süd',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'Baden-Württemberg',
   'short_name': 'BW',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
   {'long_name': 'Germany',
   'short_name': 'DE',
   'types': ['country', 'political']},
   {'long_name': '70327', 'short_name': '70327', 'types': ['postal_code']}],
   'formatted_address': 'Mercedesstraße 128, 70327 Stuttgart, Germany',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 48.7863462, 'lng': 9.2380718},
   'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
   'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 48.7876951802915,
    'lng': 9.239420780291503},
   'southwest': {'lat': 48.7849972197085, 'lng': 9.236722819708499}}},
   'place_id': 'ChIJr3KQnVbEmUcReuFmYm-eFkI',
   'types': ['establishment', 'point_of_interest']}
```

I would like to access the latitude / longitude code  'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 48.7863462, 'lng': 9.2380718}, but I am unable to do so using the regular list index method in Python. Any help is highly appreciated.

For Type I get "dict":

> type(geocode_result[0])

and for

> type(geocode_result)

I get "list".

Comment: just for future questions - it is better to tag a question with `pyhton` AND `python-3.x` - 3.x is important because of the syntax diffs to 2.7 and the general python tag helps address more ppl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format it correctly:

```
d = {'address_components': 
    [
        { 'long_name': '128', 'short_name': '128', 'types': ['street_number'] },
        { 'long_name': 'Mercedesstraße', 'short_name': 'Mercedesstraße', 'types': ['route'] },
        { 'long_name': 'Untertürkheim', 'short_name': 'Untertürkheim', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1'] },
        { 'long_name': 'Stuttgart', 'short_name': 'Stuttgart', 'types': ['locality', 'political'] },
        { 'long_name': 'Stuttgart', 'short_name': 'Süd', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'] },
        { 'long_name': 'Baden-Württemberg', 'short_name': 'BW', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political'] },
        { 'long_name': 'Germany', 'short_name': 'DE', 'types': ['country', 'political'] },
        { 'long_name': '70327', 'short_name': '70327', 'types': ['postal_code'] }
    ],
   'formatted_address': 'Mercedesstraße 128, 70327 Stuttgart, Germany',
   'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 48.7863462, 'lng': 9.2380718}, 
                'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
                'viewport': 
                    {
                        'northeast': {'lat': 48.7876951802915, 'lng': 9.239420780291503}, 
                        'southwest': {'lat': 48.7849972197085, 'lng': 9.236722819708499}
                    }
               },
   'place_id': 'ChIJr3KQnVbEmUcReuFmYm-eFkI',
   'types': ['establishment', 'point_of_interest']
}
```

And then:

```
print (d['geometry']['location'])
```

Output:

```
{'lat': 48.7863462, 'lng': 9.2380718}
```

Or if you want to address them directly:

```
lat = d['geometry']['location']['lat']   
lng = d['geometry']['location']['lng']
```